# Replace a div with an image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm trying to make a memory game in Javascript. For this purpose, I have 20 `div`'s spread across 5 rows, with 4 `div`'s in a row where each row is a `div` itself. Now, I want the contents of a particular `div` to be replaced with an image when I(the user) clicks on it. In the code shown below, I've tried to replace the contents with text, which doesn't seem to work. Only if the contents are replaced with text successfully, can I try with images.

```js
const element1 = document.getElementById('element1');
const element2 = document.getElementById('element2');
const element3 = document.getElementById('element3');
const element4 = document.getElementById('element4');
const element5 = document.getElementById('element5');
const element6 = document.getElementById('element6');
const element7 = document.getElementById('element7');
const element8 = document.getElementById('element8');
const element9 = document.getElementById('element9');
const element10 = document.getElementById('element10');
const element11 = document.getElementById('element11');
const element12 = document.getElementById('element12');
const element13 = document.getElementById('element13');
const element14 = document.getElementById('element14');
const element15 = document.getElementById('element15');
const element16 = document.getElementById('element16');
const element17 = document.getElementById('element17');
const element18 = document.getElementById('element18');
const element19 = document.getElementById('element19');
const element20 = document.getElementById('element20');


element1.addEventListener('click',function() {
    element1.innerHTML = "";
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.innerHTML = "Hello world";
    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(h1); // removing the element and then adding another element in its place
})


element2.addEventListener('click',function() {
    element2.innerHTML = "Hello world"; // directly replacing the element
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heading{
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.heading h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    /* position: fixed; */
    font-weight: bold;
}



.main-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.element{
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    background-color: indianred;
    margin: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Memory Game</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/memory-game/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="heading">
        <h2>MEMORY GAME</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="main-container" id="main">
        <div class="row" id="row1">

            <div class="element" id="element1"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element2"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element3"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element4"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element5"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="element" id="element6"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element7"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element8"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element9"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element10"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="element" id="element11"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element12"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element13"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element14"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element15"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="element" id="element16"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element17"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element18"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element19"></div>
            <div class="element" id="element20"></div>

        </div>


    </div>

    <script src="/memory-game/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now I've tried 2 different methods to replace the content. Both have been mentioned in the Javascript code.

Comment: Works according to your js code. Use `.src` to load image.

Comment: The text replace (method 2) seems to work fine in your code snippet. Method 1 also works but the new text element ends up in a different place on the screen. You could also set a backgroundi-image to the element divs.

Comment: method 2 does not replace the text, but what it does is that it puts the text inside the div, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean this?

I am delegating from the main container

```js
document.getElementById("main").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.classList.contains("element")) return;
  tgt.style.backgroundImage='url(https://via.placeholder.com/130/0000FF/808080?text=Hello+world)';
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heading {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.heading h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  /* position: fixed; */
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.element {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  background-color: indianred;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Memory Game</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/memory-game/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="heading">
    <h2>MEMORY GAME</h2>

  </div>

  <div class="main-container" id="main">
    <div class="row" id="row1">

      <div class="element" id="element1"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element2"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element3"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element4"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element5"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="element" id="element6"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element7"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element8"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element9"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element10"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="element" id="element11"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element12"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element13"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element14"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element15"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="element" id="element16"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element17"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element18"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element19"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element20"></div>

    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="/memory-game/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Alternative code

```
  var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.innerHTML = "Hello world";
  tgt.appendChild(h1);  
  const img = new Image();
  img.src="https://via.placeholder.com/130/0000FF/808080?text=Hello+world"
  tgt.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: You should check if e.target is an `.element` element. Clicking outside the tiles will bug it.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I normally always do. Thanks fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can also loop on the `.element` and use their `id`s to call an image to show onclick

basic hide/show  example

```js
let element = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
  element[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (element[i].innerHTML == "") {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src= "http://dummyimage.com/175&text="+element[i].getAttribute('id');
    element[i].appendChild(img);  
    }
    else {element[i].innerHTML="";}
  })
 }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heading {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.heading h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  /* position: fixed; */
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.element {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  background-color: indianred;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h2>MEMORY GAME</h2>
</div>

<div class="main-container" id="main">
  <div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="element" id="element1"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element2"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element3"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element4"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element" id="element6"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element7"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element8"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element9"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element10"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element" id="element11"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element12"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element13"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element14"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element15"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element" id="element16"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element17"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element18"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element19"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element20"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you mean to say that this loop will be common for every single unique `id` right?

Comment: nop, i say , that you can use an attribute,  the id or a data-attribute to go pick up your images , id can be used only once, but a data-attribute can have twice the same value within 2 .element , you could randomly set data attributes by pairs (matching an img file) for every new game  ;)

Comment: here is an example randomly dispatching a value to add to your img src   https://jsfiddle.net/gdojyprL/1 each time your run it , src will be different .

Comment: So what you're doing is that you're storing whatever needs to be displayed inside an array and then looping through that to display accordingly right?

Comment: at one point in your script you'll need an array to sort the matching tiles , this idea is only about linking img to the script and avoids `const element1 = document.getElementById('element1');`20 times ;) . here : imgName variable exists twice with the same value. https://jsfiddle.net/gdojyprL/2/ it can be used to load an image and also to see if it matches with another tile you clicked. No idea where you are about in your game script. maybe i bring confusion :(

Comment: Ok alright. One more doubt I had is that how do I display the container as it was before after it is clicked and replaced?

Comment: you need to store the click events and then check if both matches, if not reset innerHTML to " " . are you following a tutorial or making it from scratch ?

Comment: Well, I'm building everything from scratch on my own. Do you recommend me to follow any tutorial?

Comment: maybe not , but maybe at first list all the script is supposed to do . counting the click, checking matching tiles, checking tiles left or is it a win, a reset button, etc ... Else you might loose lots of time rethinking your previous bits of code / functions

Comment: Alright then. Let me get clear with the basics and I'll come back at this. Thanks for your timely help

Answer (score 0):

You might set tag attributes using JavaScript, like you did with `innerHTML`:

```
var my_img = document.createElement("img");
my_img.src = "image.png";
```

*(remember to replace image.png with what you actually needs)*

Answer (score -2):

Let be clear, you want to replace each block with `hello world` when clicked on it ?

If it is what i thought it is then, you change `innerHTML` to `innerText` first (for this hello world atleast), then

```
element1.addEventListener('click',function() {
    element1.innerText = "";
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.innerText = "Hello world";
    document.getElementById('element1').appendChild(h1); // removing the element and then adding another element in its place
})
```

By using `document.getElementById('main')` you're referring to the whole document.

Comment: Please post your answer in a comment. This is not the answer.

Comment: innerHTML is valid also as long as the content is valid for an H1

Comment: the thing here is that both `.innerHTML` and `.innerText` add the text inside the div but do not replace it.